# Add a List<object> into an object.Array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a simple way to put 2 known profiles in my profileArray list as shown below:

```
Parameters params = new Parameters();
params.plist = new Plist();
params.plist.profileArray = new[]
        {
            new Profile{name = "john", age = 12, country = "USA"},
            new Profile{name = "Brad", age = 20, country = "USA"}
        };
```

Now i have a

> `List<Profiles> UserProfiles`

which has a bunch of profiles in it.

How do i add this list to params.plist.profileArray?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

This is what is in UserProfile:

```
List<Profiles> UserProfiles 
foreach(Profiles userProfile in UserProfiles)
{
string name = userProfile.Name;
string age = userProfile.Age;
string country = userProfile.Country;
string sex = userProfile.Sex;
string isMarried = userProfile.IsMarried;
}
```

Comment: Array is fixed-size. You cannot add items to it. You can allocate new, bigger one and make `plist.profileArray` reference that new array.

Comment: I was not too sure of the title. If it does not sound correct please can someone correct it. Thanks

Comment: Can you suggest a way or any example to do that. Thanks..

Comment: Please put that in the answers so that if it works for me i can mark it.

Comment: I think you should use more appropriate names for your variables.[params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) is a speacial keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.ToArray`:

```
params.plist.profileArray = UserProfiles.ToArray();
```

If you want to add the list to the array, an array cannot be modified, you have to create a new one, for example by using `Enumerable.Concat`:

```
var newProfile = params.plist.profileArray.Concat(UserProfiles);
params.plist.profileArray = newProfile.ToArray();
```

Since these are two different classes with similar properties:

```
var profiles = UserProfiles
   .Select(up => new Profile{name = up.Name, age = up.Age, country = up.Country});
var newProfile = params.plist.profileArray.Concat(profiles);
params.plist.profileArray = newProfile.ToArray();
```

Comment: Please have a look at my edit. Maybe i was not too clear before. Thanks

Comment: If you know the type of the the data, why not use a List instead of an array? Since you are actually converting it from one to the other. Also, how does this not work as you expected? It seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
params.plist.profileArray = UserProfiles.ToArray();
```

---

How about this?

```
params.plist.profileArray =
    UserProfiles
        .Select(up => new
        {
            name = up.Name,
            age = up.Age,
            country = up.Country,
        })
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: I have a lot of other values in user profiles along with name, age and country. I don't think it will work

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an array (and arrays in C# are of fixed size), you'l need to create a new array with the combined data.

There are several ways to do this, the simplest would probably be something like this:

```
var newList = new List<Profile>();
newList.AddRange(params.plist.profileArray);
newList.AddRange(UserProfiles);

params.plist.profileArray = newList.ToArray();
```

If can you change the implementation of `Plist`, I would recommend changing the array to a `List<Profile>`. Then the code would look like this instead:

```
params.plist.profileArray.AddRange(UserProfiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
params.plist.profileArray = params
                            .plist
                            .profileArray
                            .Concat( UserProfiles )
                            .ToArray()
                            ;
```